# Rails precompile vendor/asset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, precompile

I am trying to precompile files in vendor assets folder.

In rails console in production I am getting this:

```
puts Rails.application.config.assets.precompile
#<Proc:0x000000023b2110@/home/pills/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:40 (lambda)>
(?-mix:(?:\/|\\|\A)application\.(css|js)$)
(?-mix:.*.png)

puts Rails.application.config.assets.paths
/media/pills/be3eb155-9e10-4a71-9737-c82606a3dbd4/home/ububtu/code/ccr/app/assets/fonts
/media/pills/be3eb155-9e10-4a71-9737-c82606a3dbd4/home/ububtu/code/ccr/app/assets/images
/media/pills/be3eb155-9e10-4a71-9737-c82606a3dbd4/home/ububtu/code/ccr/app/assets/javascripts
/media/pills/be3eb155-9e10-4a71-9737-c82606a3dbd4/home/ububtu/code/ccr/app/assets/stylesheets
/media/pills/be3eb155-9e10-4a71-9737-c82606a3dbd4/home/ububtu/code/ccr/vendor/assets/chosen
/media/pills/be3eb155-9e10-4a71-9737-c82606a3dbd4/home/ububtu/code/ccr/vendor/assets/javascripts
/media/pills/be3eb155-9e10-4a71-9737-c82606a3dbd4/home/ububtu/code/ccr/vendor/assets/stylesheets
/home/pills/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts
/home/pills/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
/home/pills/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/assets/javascripts
```

The last part in precompile is got in production by:

```
config.assets.precompile += [/.*.png/]
```

Why is the png file in chosen folder not being precompiled?

If I copy the png to app/assets/images, it works, I will solve the problem that way for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:png)\z/
```

I don't know where is feature here, but when I changed my code from like yours version to this, it suddenly started to work as expected. I can only suggest, that it happens because you put unescaped dot character in regexp and it can not match filename.